# Using for loops in python interpreter

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, pythoninterpreter

I'm trying to start a for loop after doing something else in python interpreter on the same line, and it throws a SyntaxError when I do so.

```
>>> a,b = 0, 1;\
... for i in range(1, 10):
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    for i in range(1, 10):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Of course I could just execute them separately here, but if I want to have this inside a function definition then I can't exactly do that. What is the correct syntax to do it in the interpreter?

Comment: I'm confused -- if you're using the semicolon to denote the end of a statement, isn't the point of that to continue the input on the same line?

Comment: *"if I want to have this inside a function definition then I can't exactly do that"* why not?

Comment: What's with the semicolon and backslash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a backslash, you are telling it to ignore the new line. So Python thought your code was `a,b = 0, 1 for i in range(1,10):`. This is clearly invalid syntax. So, you must remove the semicolon and the backslash. When you want to go to the new line, use `shift + enter key`.

After that, it should work:

[image]

Comment: Right, I thought that I'd have to demarcate each line end when defining a function with this in it, but it just stays "in" the function until I press enter twice anyways...